# Table names in an array and search within them

Tags: php, mysql

I need to search for data in different tables which are stored in an array, how can I make the query?

I have an array tables_array in which I have different table names I need to search for data with some 'where' conditions within these tables

Comment: Please show an example to clarify your input and desired output. Also, show your attempts so far.

Comment: Please explain more (with enough details) so that your problem becomes identifiable.

Comment: First start writing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search to all tables do

```
$sql = "";
$table_array=array('table_name_1', 'table_name_2', 'table_name_3');
foreach($table_array as $v) {
  if($sql !== "") {
    $sql .= " union";
  }
  $sql .= "select * from `$v` where `field_search` = '$search_value'";
}

echo $sql; //test your sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to join these three tables for one query.

For example :

```
select * from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.field='%search%'
join table3 t3 on t3.field='%search%'
where t1.field='%search%'
```